# Giving variable name to row.names in csv file

Tags: r

I have  a dataframe which look like this

```
         z
          2
          3
          4
          5
          6
          7
      >
```

after storing this dataframe in csv format using write.csv(z,"a.csv")  i get the following 
result in

```
            z
         1  2
         2  3   
         3  4
         4  5
         5  6
         6  7
```

is it possible to give variable name to the columns containing 1,2,3,4,5,6 to csv file using R

Comment: I don't think so. A hacky way to do it would be to put the row numbering into it's own column called z$rownum or whatever you wanted it called and then set "..., row.names=F)" in your write.csv() command. Pretty hacky though.

Comment: @nzcoops I would call it featurey, not hacky. :P

Comment: I suspect that what you really want is to *remove* the row names from your csv file (I've never found a use for them in an exported file anyway). You can do this with `write.csv(*, row.names=FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I understand your question well but if you try this

```
z <- data.frame( z = 2:7 )
rn <- c( "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" )
rownames( z ) <- rn
> z
  z
a 2
b 3
c 4
d 5
e 6
f 7
```

are you getting closer to what you want?

Comment: basically i want to give variable name to row.names() i.e 1,2,3.. in csv file by default its empty

Comment: Sorry, I got that wrong. But for this, nzcoops' method should work just fine? Or if not, maqxybe you can explain a little more about your goal.

Comment: @nzcoops method is fine but is ther any method without storing in new variable named z$rownum

Answer (score 0):

`write.csv` doesn't allow you to change a number of parameters, including `col.names`:

```
 for (argname in c("append", "col.names", "sep", "dec", "qmethod")) if (!is.null(Call[[argname]])) 
        warning(gettextf("attempt to set '%s' ignored", argname), 
            domain = NA)
```

`write.table` allows you to change `col.names`, but only for the number of columns in your data. `?write.table` has the following advice for CSV files:

> By default there is no column name for a column of row names. If
>   col.names = NA and row.names = TRUE a blank column name is added,
>   which is the convention used for CSV files to be read by spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like `df$Record_ID <- seq.int(nrow(df))` and then set row.names=FALSE in your write.csv statement.